# How to expose data in my WCF Service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soa

This is somewhat of a silly question.But...

I am exposing a service of Street locations. What I have been doing so far is getting my data using Entity Framework and parsing the data into XML using XElement. Then in my service layer, I am returning the XElement to be exposed in my service.

Is this the proper way of exposing data? Since WCF is using the Data Contract which in turn serializes to XML anyway, is it a bad practice to convert it myself to XML?

I can also return a List to accomplish the same thing. However, this means I have no control on how the XML would look...

What best practice can I follow and where can I read some good info on best practices. Ive been searching in this site but there are a lot of different topics when it comes to best practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bad practice to exchange XML, however, I think you would benefit more from exchanging type-safe data. Just create classes and decorate them with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes. WCF will take care of serializing them between your service and clients. This way you'll have objects with type-safe properties in the client code and this data will probably be a lot easier to consume.

Comment: Since I am returning a collection of "Streets", why would I need to decorate my "Street" class with Data Contract?

Comment: The DataContract attribute marks your type as serializable for the DataContractSerializer (that's what WCF uses to serialize your data into XML). See [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [DataContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) ... you don't have to serialize it by yourself ... Datacontracts are (imho) the better Way.

Comment: But then what if I want to format the XML in a certain way...how do I do that without creating the XML myself?